# Do USA DS games work in AUS?

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-ds

I bought a Nintendo DSI console in 2011 from Australia and I would like to buy a DS game online but it ships from America. Would the game still work on my device?

Comment: Hi Lauren, welcome to the site! US games should work in Aus for Nintendo DS. (Note that this isn't the case for 3DS games) :-)

Comment: Thanks! If the console I bought is a DSI, will just a plain DS game work?

Comment: yep that should work fine. :-)

Comment: Depends on the DS game. I have a Japanese DSi and found at least one EU DS game (Pictogram) wasn't recognised due to the region lock, but the cart worked in my old original DS. Most games should be OK though.